# Create unique ID by adding 1 to the last ID record in text file

Tags: java, file, io

I'm writing an ordering system where all data is recorded in a text file called "order.txt". I want to create unique order ids automatically by adding 1 to the last order id from the text file once order has been made.

Example

```
ID    ,Food    ,    Food Quantity    ,    Drink    ,Drink Quantity
/1    /Fried Chicken:    /1     /Sprite    /2

/2    /Fried Chicken:    /1     /Sprite    /1

/1    /Fried Chicken:    /1     /Sprite    /1
```

But the Id keep start with 1 when the application is restart.
How can I solve this problem?

Code

```java
    private static int AUTO_ID = 1;
    private int id;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String FoodChoice = FoodComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String QtyFood = FoodQ.getValue().toString();
    String DrinkChoice = DrinksComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String QtyDrinks = DrinkQ.getValue().toString();

    AtomicInteger ID = new AtomicInteger(0);
    int res = ID.getAndIncrement();

            try {    
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("order.txt");         
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.isEmpty())
                    break;

                String[] rowData = line.split(";");
                
                
                }
     
            } 
            
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(order.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(order.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    

    try{
                AUTO_ID++;
                this.id = AUTO_ID;
                
        FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("order.txt",true);
        wr.write("/"+ Id+"    /"+FoodChoice+":    /"+QtyFood+"     /"+DrinkChoice+"    /"+QtyDrinks+"\n");
        wr.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));        
                    
        wr.close();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
        
   }
}
```

Comment: If you're recording then you will be reading the record won't you? So then you can count the lines as you read. btw variable names begin lower case in Java and are in [camel case](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions). I would recommend you use the higher level ```PrintWriter```  rather than ```FileWriter```

Comment: Store the ID in a file too. Better yet use an embedded database like H2. With a bit of SQL you then can make reports like food preferences.

Comment: @JoopEggen My lecturer want us to store all data in text files, and i also put 'AUTO_ID++` and `this.id = AUTO_ID;` to the second `try{}` but  order id still start with 1 once application restart.